# Split file to upload with jquery and php: solution

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, upload

Here the solution i've implemented to bypass a problem with a website.

Let's start with the problem: 2 apache web servers using php. The servers are behind a load balancer. Load balancer and servers "speak" in https but...if you try to upload a file bigger than 1MB the time spent is about 5 minutes, few seconds instead if the file is 100KB or if you use directl connection to the web server.

So the problem is on the load balancer: i'm not a network manager nor a system manager, so i can't say if it's a traffic problem, a wrong configuration on the balancer or what else.

So one workaround is to try to send fragments of 100KB (few seconds for each upload) then reassemble all on server side with a php script. Another step ahead is to use the fake-concurrency offered by jquery (remind that javascript is single-threaded) to make more submissions at once.

How?

I wrote the complete solution (see the answer below) just becouse i've found only incomplete solutions or a solution referencing wordpress tools (that i'm not using).

Note: The session is shared between the servers thanks to memcache, so php-side we will work with $_session variable to be sure to have all the shared data available on all web servers.

Comment: The answer must be in a different post, not on the post of the question, can you edit it to remove the answer and post the answer as an answer of your question please?

Comment: the solution is in the answer below, the question is "how to implement upload split using jquery and php"

Answer (score 0):

So that's the solution.
First of all the html code:

```
<script src="/js/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script><!-- jquery 3.4.1 -->
<form id="fupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p id="dbi-upload-progress">Choose a file then click Upload.</p>
    <input id="dbi-file-upload" type="file" name="dbi_import_file" /><br><br>
    <input id="dbi-upload-submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

So, let's start with javascript section. Here we are the variables used globally:

```
var max_size   = 5*1024*1024; // Max upload size: 5MB
var slice_size = 100*1024;    // Max size of each fragment: 100 KB
var concurrency = 4;          // Max thread number 
var start_time_total=$.now(); // Time var, just to check upload performance
var file = {};                // Pointer to file to upload
var abort = false;            // Flag used to abort operation
var goals = 0;                // Counter of parallel threads completed
var percent = 0;              // Percent of progress
```

Then we need the jquery initialization function to prevent standard form submit and start the transaction:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent standard submit

        // Point to the file
        file = document.querySelector( '#dbi-file-upload' ).files[0];

        // Checking file size and extension
        if(file.size > max_size) {
            alert("Warning! \nFiles bigger than 5MB not supported");
            return;
        } else if(file.name.endsWith('.part')) {
            alert("Warning! \nFiles with .part extension not supported");
            return;
        }

        init_upload_file(); // Beginning the transaction
    });
});
```

Next we need to call once our php script to initialize server-side the session to avoid concurrency and session-sharing errors.

```
function init_upload_file() {
        // Global browser-side variables init, form disable and some console logging
        abort = false; goals = 0; percent = 0; start_time_total=$.now();
        $('#dbi-upload-submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('#dbi-upload-progress').html('Upload init...');
        console.log("Start global transaction @"+ new Date(start_time_total));

        // First call to server with 'init' parameter
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("init", 1);
        var start_time=$.now();
        console.log("start init call @"+new Date(start_time));
        $.ajax( {
            url: "/myPhpFileUrl", type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: false,
               cache: false, processData:false, data: formData,
            error: function( data ) {
                $('#dbi-upload-progress').html( 'Init call failed' ); // You can use an alert
                console.log( "Init call ko after "+($.now()-start_time)+" msecs; error: "+data );
                console.log( "End global transaction after "+ ($.now()-start_time_total)+" msecs");
                $('#dbi-upload-submit').removeAttr("disabled"); // Re-enable the form submit
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $( '#dbi-upload-progress' ).html( 'Sending file...' );
                // Calling 'core' function to send multiple fragments
                for(var i=0;i<concurrency;i++)
                    upload_file( (i * (slice_size + 1)) );
            }
        });
}
```

So here you are the 'core' function made to be called in (js-fake-)multi-thread mode:

```
function upload_file( start ) { // Start argument is the offset used to read a fragment
    if(abort) return; // Check if some thread is in error (abort the transaction)
    // Initialize file reader and put in blob var the fragment to send
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var next_slice = start + slice_size + 1;
    var blob = file.slice( start, next_slice );
    reader.onloadend = function( event ) {
        if ( event.target.readyState !== FileReader.DONE ) { return; }
        // preparing the form data to send and calling the server
        var slice_id=Math.floor(start / slice_size);
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("fileUpload", blob, "." + slice_id + ".part");
        formData.append("part", slice_id);
        var start_time=$.now();
        console.log("Start sending slice "+slice_id+" @"+new Date(start_time));
        $.ajax( {
            url: "/myPhpFileUrl", type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: false,
            cache: false, processData:false, data: formData,
            error:   function( data ) {
                console.log("slice "+slice_id+" send error after "+($.now()-start_time)+" msecs");
                console.log("error: "+data );
                console.log("End global transaction after "+ ($.now()-start_time_total)+" msecs");
                if(abort) return; // Maybe some other thread was in error...
                // If it's the first error we inform the user and re-enable the form submit
                $('#dbi-upload-progress').html('Upload error'); // You can use an alert
                $('#dbi-upload-submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                abort=true;
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                if(abort) return; // Some other thread is in error, so we exit
                console.log("slice "+slice_id+" ok after "+($.now()-start_time)+" msecs");
                // Calculate progress and next offset
                var size_done = start + slice_size;
                var percent_done = Math.floor( ( size_done / file.size ) * 100 );
                var real_next_slice=start + ((slice_size + 1)* concurrency);
                if ( real_next_slice < file.size ) {
                    // Let's inform the user with the best upload % progress
                    if(percent < percent_done) percent=percent_done;
                    $( '#dbi-upload-progress' ).html( 'Sending file (' + percent + '%)' );
                    upload_file( real_next_slice ); // More to upload, call function recursively
                } else { 
                    // No more fragments to read
                    // if all fragments have been sent we commit the transaction 
                    goals++;
                    if(goals==concurrency) {
                        $('#dbi-upload-progress').html( 'Completing upload...' );
                        commit_uploaded_file();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL( blob );
}
```

Now the last piece of our jquery puzzle: the commit call. In few words we call for one last time our php script to reassemble the file.

```
function commit_uploaded_file() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileUpload", new Blob() , file.name);
    formData.append("fileType", file.type);
    var start_time=$.now();
    console.log("start final commit @"+new Date(start_time));
    $.ajax( {
        url: "/myPhpFileUrl", type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: false,
        cache: false, processData:false, data: formData,
        error:   function( data ) {
            $( '#dbi-upload-progress' ).html( 'Upload failed' );
            console.log( "Commit transaction ko after "+($.now()-start_time)+" msecs");
            console.log( "Errore: "+data );
            console.log( "End global transaction after "+ ($.now()-start_time_total)+" msecs");
            $('#dbi-upload-submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            $( '#dbi-upload-progress' ).html( 'Upload completed' );
            console.log( "Commit transaction ok after "+($.now()-start_time)+" msecs");
            console.log( "End global transaction after "+ ($.now()-start_time_total)+" msecs");
            $('#dbi-upload-submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

That's all folks!

...ok, just joking ;-)

We need the myPhpFileUrl php file: an if/else branch to manage initialization phase, fragment upload phase and commit phase.

```
$uploadedFileId='fileUpload';
$name        = $_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['name'];
$tmp_name    = $_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['tmp_name'];
$type        = $_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['type'];

if($_POST['init'] && $_POST['init']==1)  {
    // Init part, let's clean session and prepare for the upload
    if(isset($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'])) {
        array_splice($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'], 1);
        unset($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE']);
    }
    $_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'][0]='';
    die(new JsonSuccess("Init session ok")); // Print a simple json string and exit
} else if(substr($name, -5) === '.part') {
    // chunk upload part, this can be executed on different web servers in different threads
    $part=$_POST['part'];
    if(isset($_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['tmp_name'])) {
        if($fp = fopen($_FILES[$uploadedFileId]['tmp_name'],'rb')) {
            $contents = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $contents .= fread($fp, 8192);
            }
            $_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'][$part] = $contents;
            die(new JsonSuccess("Chunk ".$name.": loaded ".strlen($contents)." bytes"); // Print a simple json string and exit
        }
    }
} else {
    // Commit part: let's assemble the final file in /tmp folder
    $myfile = fopen("/tmp/".$name, "w")
        or die("Write error: /tmp/".$name);
    for ($row = 0; isset($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'][$row]) ; $row++) {
        fwrite($myfile, $_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'][$row]);
    }
    fclose($myfile);

    // Clean the session
    array_splice($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE'], 1);
    unset($_SESSION[session_id()]['UPLOADED_FILE']);
    die(new JsonSuccess("Commit success!")); // print a simple json string and exit
}
```